# perform operations on excel data sheet using java

Tags: java, excel

there are four columns in excel sheet

1. I need to perform operations on three columns and display the result on the fourth one.
2. [Image with data in excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xBE2h.png)
3. If I perform B9-D9 then the result is equal to C9.
4. when this happens the output should be as "matched".
5. i need to know how to  access each row and column and perform the  necessary operation on it.
   See if you can help me and let me know if any additional details are required.

   ```
   package com.infy;

   import java.io.File;
   import java.io.FileInputStream;
   import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
   import java.io.IOException;
   import java.util.Iterator;



   import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
   import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
   import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
   import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
   import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;


   public class ReconMatch {
       public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, 
   FileNotFoundException{
           // TODO Auto-generated method stub
           String excelFilePath ="C:/Users/akshay.kuchankar/Documents/demo.xlsx";
           FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new 
   File(excelFilePath));

           Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
           Sheet firstSheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
           Iterator<Row> iterator = firstSheet.iterator();

           while (iterator.hasNext()) {
               Row nextRow = iterator.next();
               Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = nextRow.cellIterator();

                while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                    Cell cell = cellIterator.next();

                    //what should be the basic approach or the syntax to perform the operaiton??
                }
                System.out.println();
             }
             workbook.close();
             inputStream.close();

           }

       }
   ```

   ---

   ```
    for(int i= 0; i<firstSheet.getRow(0).getCell(0).getNumericCellValue(); i++)
               {

                   FGAmount = firstSheet.getRow(1).getCell(1).getNumericCellValue();
                   //  System.out.println(FGAmount);
                   difference = firstSheet.getRow(1).getCell(3).getNumericCellValue();
                   value = FGAmount + difference;

               }
                       alconAmount = firstSheet.getRow(1).getCell(2).getNumericCellValue();

          //           result = firstSheet.getRow(1).getCell(4).getStringCellValue();

           }               
       }
       try {
           if(value== alconAmount){
               firstSheet.getRow(1).getCell(4).setCellValue("Manual Matched");
               System.out.println("matched");
           }                       

       } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
           System.out.println(e);
       }
       // System.out.println(result);

        workbook.close();
        inputStream.close();
   ```

Comment: Please avoid CAPITAL letters (it's like shouting inside a library)

Comment: okay...will make sure doesn't happen next time @agerom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the API for your library:

https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html

You can interact with the cell in a number of ways, for example:
`cell.setCellValue("My new value");`

As for how to get values form cells and check against them you can do something a bit like this example where we do a bit of math and compare the values:

```
//Value of row 9, column 1 (column B)
String B9 = firstSheet.getRow(9).getCell(1).getStringCellValue();

//Value of row 9, column 2 (column C)
String D9 = firstSheet.getRow(9).getCell(2).getStringCellValue();

//Value of row 9, column 3 (column D)
String D9 = firstSheet.getRow(9).getCell(3).getStringCellValue();

//do math B9 - D9
double value = Double.parseDouble(B9) - Double.parseDouble(D9);

//check if C9 matches the result of B9 - D9
if(value == Double.parseDouble(C9))
{
    //if it matches set cell E9 to display "Matched" and print out a message
    firstSheet.getRow(9).getCell(4).setCellValue("matched");
    System.out.println("matched");
}
```

I have not tested this code, but it should point you in the right direction.

Obviously there are things you should do like putting this in a loop rather than hard coding values, and you should check the column name to the make sure you have the right column before getting your values, and then you should check that the cell is a number and not text etc.

---

Edit in reply to your comment. Here is some code that will go over every row in a sheet except row 1 and will do exactly the same thing as in my example above and write "matched" in column E if column B - column D is equal to column C:

```
Iterator<Row> iterator = firstSheet.iterator();

while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    Row nextRow = iterator.next();

    //Check to make sure we skip the first row because that has all the column names:
    if (nextRow.getRowNum() != 0){
        //Get cell values of the current row
        String columnB = nextRow.getCell(1).getStringCellValue();
        String columnC = nextRow.getCell(2).getStringCellValue();
        String columnD = nextRow.getCell(3).getStringCellValue();

        try{
            //do math column B - column D
            double value = Double.parseDouble(columnB) - Double.parseDouble(columnD);

            //check if column C matches the result of (column B - column D)
            if(value == Double.parseDouble(columnC)){
                //if it matches set text in column E to "matched"
                nextRow.getCell(4).setCellValue("matched");
                //print to console showing if a row matched
                System.out.println("Row " + (nextRow.getRowNum()+1) + " matched");
            }
        }
        catch(NumberFormatException nfe){
            //do nothing here, this will happen if a cell contains text instead of numbers 
        }
        catch(NullPointerException npe){
            //Something else happened, you can probably ignore this as well but it will pay to throw a stack trace just in case something is wrong with this code
            npe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I understood the logical part. Thanks! But still  I dont know how to access all the rows and columns with for loops.       Since there are four columns should i use four for loops?? Please let me know @sorifiend

Comment: I recommend a single loop that changes the row number because the colon numbers will be the same each time. And in each loop just get the value of all 4 columns like in my example above.

Comment: Can you tell me now how I can do it?? Look what I've done,,I know the code is no where near the concept. but that is what i'm trying to understand @sorifiend

Comment: @AkshayKumar see my edit above showing how to do the same action on every row in the sheet.

Comment: Thank you man!! you've been a great help!! I'll try this. if something comes up, i'll get back!!